# Centering a table in CSS isn't Working

Tags: html, css

I'm using [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) and reading the following links:

[Center-align a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073188/center-align-a-html-table)

[Center a table](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/)

[CSS: Centered tables](http://catcode.com/csstips/center_table.html)

about how to center a table using CSS, as `align` has been deprecated. However, none of them are working, the code suggested in the 3 links to center a table looks like this:

```
.centered-table {
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto%; 
}
```

My code:

CSS:

```
.maintbl {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto%; 
}
```

HTML:

```
 <table class="maintbl" id="tblMain">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello world<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of centering, it appears on the right side. I copied the code from the last link directly into the editor, and the result was the same. What wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `margin-right: auto%;` isn't valid. You can specify auto *or* a percentage, but not together. https://jsfiddle.net/8wherLxu/

Comment: @j08691 - Nevermind, I figured out what the problem was. Error on my part. Thanks!

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: @j08691 - What you said the auto% isn't valid. When I looked at my code again, the % for left isn't there, and a re-check of the last link verified that the % isn't there in the code. It's just auto and ; no percent.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't valid"?

Comment: @j08691 - you said it wasn't valid and I rechecked my code.

Comment: `auto%` is a completely invalid value, so I'm not sure why you think it's valid. The browser may be correcting it for you, but on it's own it's not valid.

Comment: @j08691 - Sure do. It was a silly mistake on my part. Either percent or auto; but not a combination.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721586/how-do-i-responsively-center-text-inside-of-a-div/41721874#41721874. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better practice for table center. just use css on the table tag

example.

```
 table {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```