# How do I responsively center text inside of a <div>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a `<div>` that contains three `<div>`s.
In each of those `<div>` elements is a `<p>` element with text and 2 nested  elements to make a radial progress bar. What I need is to put the text in the middle of the circles, and do it responsively using pure CSS. I need something like this:

[image: Wanted result]

The code has flaws, like that `<p>` inside of a `<span>` but I am fixing it in the new version with the help you guys provide.

```css
.radius-container div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.radius-container div:first-child {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.radius {
  padding-top: 11em;
  height: 30em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #858280;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.radius3 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10%;
  height: 15em;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #858280;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15em;
}

.radius3 p {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="radius-container">
  <div><span class="radius"><p>SERBIAN<br>100%</p></span></div>
  <div><span class="radius"><p>ENGLISH<br>100%</p></span></div>
  <div><span class="radius3"><p>GERMAN<br>25%</p></span></div>
</div>
```

See also this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v0srgb6/)

Comment: Could you provide a JSFilddle with what you managed to do so far ?

Comment: can you please provide the code that you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: I edited it, sorry it took so long

Comment: That's OK; the question is still answered in the duplicate link I commented above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for long time for this issue, I found an generic solution which solves this kind of requeriments. I am proud of it, simple and elegant :)

```
.center-element{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Hoping it helps, any doubt let me know. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div with a border-radius to 50%. After, you can use the flex display to center verticaly and horizontaly.

html

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div div span {
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>Serbian</span><span>100%</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>Serbian</span><span>50%</span>
  </div>
  <div><span>Serbian</span><span>25%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you.

```
 .innerDiv { 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
```