# HTML-CSS: How to put a form/table with fieldset to the center but keeping the fieldset as the same size as the form/table?

Tags: html, css

In HTML for a `<form>` used together with a `<table>`. It such as:

```
<form ...>
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   ...
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

To put this *form/table* in the middle of the page is used `CSS` as follows:

```
table {
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Credits from:

- [Center-align a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073188/center-align-a-html-table)

Until all is ok.

The situation is when is added `<fieldset>` and `legend` to the `<form>`, well really to the `<table>`. Therefore the structure is now as follows

```
<form ...>
<fieldset>
<legend>Some Description ...</legend>
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   ...
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here arises two situations:

1. How to put the `<fieldset>`'s border as the same size as the form/table itself?

Here as applied

```
fieldset {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

Credits from:

- [Is there any way to have a fieldset width only be as wide as the controls in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302495/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-fieldset-width-only-be-as-wide-as-the-controls-in-the)

Even when it works as expected, the `<table>` returns to the left.

**Question**

- How to put a form/table with fieldset to the center but keeping the fieldset as the same size as the form/table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
form {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
fieldset {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Some Description ...</legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Remember to close your fieldset tag.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, let me test your code - btw I changed from `0 auto;` to `0px auto;`, not sure if is the same. If is the same consider to update it to `0px auto;`

Comment: 0px, 0rem, 0%, etc. is just zero, It is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318471/property-0-or-property-0px-in-css